# "Typewriter"-like printing not working in CMD or py.exe, but works in VS Code Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, random

I'm studying software development and we've started using python, and for an exercise I wanted to make a "fancy" printing style. With some help from the internet I managed to get this to work in the terminal of VS Code, which I've been using- but when running the .py file on its own or through CMD, the loop is ran as many times as it should, and only then prints the output all at once.

```
from time import *
from random import *
from numbers import *

# Slow printing function- prints 1 character at a time
def slowPrint(line):
    for char in line: # For every character (char) in the string (line)
        t = uniform(0.03, 0.3)
        print(char,end="") # Print the character, end on nothing to ensure no spaces between characters
        sleep(t) # Sleep for t amount of seconds

# Conversation
slowPrint("Message 1."), sleep(0.5), slowPrint(" Message 2.\n")


input("Press enter;")
```

What I believe it should do, and what it does in the VS Code Terminal, is that it prints every character on its own, with a random delay between each character. I can't figure out what is making this different between VS Code and CMD.

I hope someone here knows this :> thanks in advance!

Comment: THE WORST WAY TO IMPORT ANYTHING. Sorry but you shouldn't use `*` when importing, especially in this case where you do it from multiple libraries. It is bad practice already, but this is more than that. you don't know all the functions in those libraries so you could overwrite some, can cause some very hard to debug issues, besides that doesn't help readability at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flush=True` to the print function:

```py
print(char, end="", flush=True)
```

Basically `flush` well... flushes the data immediately instead of buffering it ([w3schools reference to `print` function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp))

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Regarding the imports, I had no clue- this was how I was learned it in class.

Comment: @pinkflameinthepan well, that's not great, it is simply bad programming practice, for your case you could simply do `from time import sleep` and `from random import uniform`, that is it, you occupy very little of the namespace, it is kinda clear where the function come from (also you are not using the `numbers` library so that import in your given example is useless). The one example would be (especially without knowing the packages well) is when `from tkinter import *` and `from tkinter.ttk import *`, they both have same classes but not same arguments for them, error is therefore confusing